# SQLAlchemy: modify value on attribute set

Tags: sqlalchemy, geoalchemy2

I have a following model:

```py
class Place(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'places'

    id: Mapped[BigIntPk]
    name: Mapped['str'] = mapped_column(
        String(128, collation=RU_RU_CE_COLLATION_NAME),
    )
    address: Mapped['str'] = mapped_column(
        String(256, collation=RU_RU_CE_COLLATION_NAME),
    )
    region_name: Mapped[BigIntType] = mapped_column(
        ForeignKey('regions.name', ondelete='RESTRICT', onupdate='CASCADE',),
    )
    coordinates = mapped_column(
        Geography(geometry_type='POINT', nullable=True, spatial_index=False),
    )

    strikes: Mapped[list['Strike']] = relationship(
        secondary='strike_to_place_associations',
        passive_deletes=True,
        back_populates='places',
    )
    region: Mapped['Region'] = relationship()
```

Thing is unlike with all other attributes whenever i need to set **coordinates** and sucessfully save model instance in database later i need to assign this exact attribute as :

```py
from geoalchemy2 import WKTElement
coordinates = WKTElement(f'POINT({lat} {lon})')
```

instead of assigning coordinates in more usual format as tuple of lat, lon **(22.8, 33.3)** for example.

Question is  - is it possible to assign **coordinates** attribute with bare tuple of (lat, lon) and then mutate it on assign or before save in database as it specified above?

I sort of found how to do it via **events** but it is quite hidenn away and implicit  -> i dont like it this way....